# Why doesn't webpack gives an error with the extracted css/sass file

Tags: css, webpack, sass, extract

In my electron with react project I've been trying to extract the css file, but with no success, if I use the style-loader, it works fine, but when trying to extract it to a separate css file, it doesn't find it. Here is the error it gives me **in the gitbash console**:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 4:0-23
    [0] Module not found: Error: path argument is not a string
    [0]
    [0] ERROR in ./src/index.js 5:0-30
    [0] Module not found: Error: path argument is not a string
    [0]
    [0] webpack 5.24.2 compiled with 2 errors in 2746 ms
```

This is the code it refers to in **index.js**:

```
import 'normalize.css'
import './styles/styles.scss'
```

This is my **webpack.config.js** file:

```
    const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const miniCSSExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env.test' });
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    require('dotenv').config({ path: '.env.development' });
}

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isProduction = env === 'production'
    const CSSExtract = new miniCSSExtractPlugin({
        filename: 'styles.css'
    })
    const isDev = isProduction ? 'production' : 'development'
    return {
        mode: isDev,
        entry: './src/index.js',
        devtool: isProduction ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map',
        target: 'electron-renderer',
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader'
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: [/\.s[ac]ss$/i, /\.css$/i],
                    use: [{loader: CSSExtract.loader}, {loader: 'css-loader'}, {loader: 'sass-loader'}]
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            CSSExtract,
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY),
                'process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN),
                'process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL),
                'process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID),
                'process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET),
                'process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID': JSON.stringify(process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID)
            })
        ],
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js'],
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'dist'),
            filename: 'app.js'
        }
    }
}
```

And I do import the output files in my index.html
And here is my **.babelrc** file:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```